# Android HttpClient Two different httpposts not working?

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient

I have the following code.

- I want to post on the first time the user press a button that the data will be send to httpclient and will return data. This works fine (Button 1). When a user press button 1 it will give the right results.
- Then I want to post a second time with different data to the httpclient. When a user press button 2. The data will be send to the function but the logs (see code) returns in the exceptions every time NULL. So I think it will not send to httpclient and will not fill the httppost with the data I want to send.

My question is, what do I wrong or do I forget?

- Do I need to create a second httpclient handler?
- Do I need to create a second httppost handler?

Please help.

Thank you.

```js
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;

    import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.util.MyHttpClient;

    public class Login extends Activity  {
      

        HttpPost httppost;
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        ProgressDialog offlineDialog = null;
        String logged, token, valid;
        String expired = "expired";
        String status, responseContent = "0";
        String msg = "";

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
          httpclient=new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
          httppost= new HttpPost("https://www.test.com/json/index.php");
          
          b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
          c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shareData);
          
          b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "","Validating user...", true);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            login();
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });

           String username = 'abc';
           String password = 'xxx';
           String token = '12321abcksadkm';

c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    offlineDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "", "Share content...", true);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // This will be executed but will give NULL and offcourse no results
                            share.connectDP(username,password,"share","18228",token);
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
          
        }
        
        void login(){
        try{

            final byte[] SALT;

            Random random = new Random();
            random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            byte[] buf = new byte[20];
            random.nextBytes(buf);
            SALT = buf;

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",SALT.toString().trim()));

            Log.i("Salt", "Key =" + SALT.toString().trim());
            Log.i("test", "test" + nameValuePairs);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            //Log.d("Response", responseContent );

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseContent);
            JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    logged = json_data.getString("status"); // obtain status
                    token = json_data.getString("token"); // obtain token
                    valid = json_data.getString("valid"); // obtain validation period
                    expired = "no";
                    Log.i("Logged JSON", "Result?" + json_data.getString("status"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
      }

      public void connectDP(String username, String password, String action, String id, String token){

        // This is passed, it returns the data = :)
        Log.i("connect", "username" + username);
        Log.i("connect", "password" + password);
        Log.i("connect", "action" + action);
        Log.i("connect", "id" + id);
        Log.i("connect", "token" + token);

        try{

            final byte[] SALT;

            Random random = new Random();
            random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            byte[] buf = new byte[20];
            random.nextBytes(buf);
            SALT = buf;

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",SALT.toString().trim()));

            Log.i("Salt", "Key =" + SALT.toString().trim());
            Log.i("test", "test" + nameValuePairs);

            //// <!---- After here it will break, but no any error or warning -----!>

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            //Log.d("Response", responseContent );

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseContent);
            JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    logged = json_data.getString("status"); // obtain status
                    token = json_data.getString("token"); // obtain token
                    valid = json_data.getString("valid"); // obtain validation period
                    expired = "no";
                    Log.i("Logged JSON", "Result?" + json_data.getString("status"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

      
    }
```

```js
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/connect﹕ usernameabc
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/connect﹕ passwordxxx
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/connect﹕ actionshare
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/connect﹕ id18228
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/connect﹕ token12321abcksadkm
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/test 1﹕ test[username=abc, password=xxx, requestAction=share, requestFile=18228, load_remote_token=12321abcksadkm
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/test 1a﹕ testnull
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/test 2﹕ testnull
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/test 2a﹕ testnull
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/test 3﹕ testnull
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/test 4﹕ testnull
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/test 4a﹕ testnull
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/test 5﹕ 0
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/System.out﹕ Exception : Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-03 19:33:22.380  12220-12220/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/Log share﹕ [ 04-03 19:33:25.390   169:0x204 W/InputManagerService ]
    Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4156a2c8
```

```js
package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.util;
import android.content.Context;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.R;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    final Context _context;

    public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
        // to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", (org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory) newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
            // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = _context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
            try {
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
                // Also provide the password of the keystore
                trusted.load(in, "xxxxxxxx".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
            // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
            // for the verification of the server certificate.
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
            // Hostname verification from certificate
            // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.Login.connectDP(Login.java:247)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater.CustomGridOfflineMedia$2.onClick(CustomGridOfflineMedia.java:200)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14110)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-04 22:39:06.890  15395-15395/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the logcat please

Comment: I've posted the logcat. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

i hope somebody more qualified will answer your question soon, until then something to maybe look into:

HttpPost.reset inherited from AbstractExecutionAwareRequest
says in the docs:

"Resets internal state of the request making it reusable."

making me think that maybe if you do not reset the httppost object it isn't reusable...

src: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/AbstractExecutionAwareRequest.html#reset()

Comment: links might change in future, so better if you can define the concept in brief here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the logcat, your API doesnt response a valid JSON format.

It must be "response" : "0" or something liek that instead of plain 0.

I suggest you to check the server side code for connectDB function and what it returns.

Comment: Thanks, but the first onclicklistener (b) that calls login(); = working. If I replace the second onclicklistener (c) with the same function so I replace everything in connectDP with the code that is in login() it will still give no result. The server side script is working fine. I think it has something to do with a double httppost or something with closing the httppost and starting a second httppost.

Comment: first one may work, but the error comes with the second API, have you verified that ?  Verify your response with a tool like   rest-client or poster

Comment: The response = {"result":[{"status":1,"message":"Share request succesfull.","token":"$6$rounds=5000$usesomeDPStringf$o90sKrB.l9gXiPeYzvVc60bggWqt9yoW2Jbj1LpyeRGW5.BE4eu8ylFsXs6nqvCTgCGock8P7GJxew7XDXA9s\/","valid":"1432918351","file":"{\"success\":true}"}]}

Comment: Maybe it is breaking on this, "file":"{\"success\":true}"}]}. The response is valid I think but maybe not for android. I will try to figure this out with isJSONValid(). I will post a message when I have implemented this.

Comment: It is valid. But even when I do twice the same request (see edited code) it will not post.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by changing some code.

Comment: please put the updated code as answer, and accept it. It will help others in future cases.

Comment: I moved the second httppost to another view. I did not found the answer to do two times a httpost in 1 view.